# JQuery .submit() a FORM doesn't work

Tags: php, html, jquery

I'm increasing my system by entering the functionality of loading a page inside a div dynamically, in the other words, the central area of the page is updated. For this I am using the JQuery. But even I having a problem which is the following, when submitting the same FORM one has to load the next page via JQuery-Ajax to send the post to use the data on this second page.

The funny thing is that I'm not getting the pick. Submit() the FORM always and only in one case. I will post the HTML below the two situations:

In the html code below warning test that I created within the form.submit () is being displayed.

```
    <form id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" name="frmPadrao" method="POST" action="HTTP://localhost/fwsibe/index.php/acesso/listarSistemasValidar">
        <br>
        <fieldset id="tabelainfo" style="width: 560px;">
            <legend style="color: #083C06;">
                <b>Dados</b>
            </legend>
            <br>
            <table id="tabelainfo">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>SIBE:* </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="slSibe">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="btConfirmar">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <br>
    </form>
```

In the second code warning. Submit () is not displayed, or is not recognized submission form:

```
    <form id="form" accept-charset="utf-8" name="frmPadrao" method="POST" action="HTTP://localhost/sibe/index.php/almembal/motivoajustealm/pesquisar">
        <br>
        <fieldset id="tabelainfo" style="width: 560px;">
            <legend style="color: #083C06;">
                <b>Filtrar por:</b>
            </legend>
            <br>
            <table id="tabelainfo">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <b>SubTipo Produto:* </b>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select name="slSubTipo">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Confirmar" name="btConfirmar">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <a title="" onclick="window.open('HTTP://localhost/sibe/index.php/almembal/motivoajustealm/incluir', '_blank', 'width=800,height=600,scrollbars=yes,status=yes,resizable=yes,screenx=0,screeny=0');" href="javascript:void(0);">Incluir</a>
        </div>
        <br>
        <table id="tabelainfo">
            <tbody>
                <tr id="corpotabela">
                    <td align="center">Não existem Motivos de Ajuste cadastrados para esta pesquisa.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Below the JQuery script that is already properly initialized in the HEAD of the page, in addition, already tested for other enventos as $ (this). Click and everything is ok.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function() {
        alert("SUBMIT FORM");
//        alert($(this));
//        console.log($(this));


//        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
//            $("#divCentral").html(data);
//        });

//        return false;

    });
});
```

Could you help me find the bug that causes. Submit () is not recognized by JQuery?

Edited:

I already discovered the source of the problem. Looks like that when the component  is drawn for a page loaded by jquery-ajax, the event .submit() doesn't works, but when the page is loaded for default away, the event works.

The problem is that the  is loaded by Ajax, and the JQuery function don't recognize it. I'am creating the function for load the central page of the template by a ajax request to a file. I have two functions, the first just for test, and the second I'am creating for works with the $_POST. The JQuery function for now is well:

```
function carregaUrl(url) {
    //alert("carregaUrl=" + url);
    $("#divCentral").load(url);
    console.log($('form').attr('name'));



}

    function carregaUrl2(url) {

    var data = $("form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data
    }).done(function(data) {
        $("#divCentral").html(data);
    });

}
```

Comment: jQuery code which you have shown is correct,but remember other than above code you might have some more code,if any thing wrong in that code that total jQuery fails.So, first check javascript console for errors and try to debug it or post here those errors.

Comment: So you have 2 form elements , both with the same `id="form"` ?

Comment: No, it's just one form per page. The exemple above are two different pages.

Comment: Uncomment `return false`?

Comment: I tested with ''$('form').change()'' but the problem persists, no iteration happens.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here, is that the handler fires, starts the alert, and then form submit occurs, effectively reloading your page.

You need your event handler to return false if you want to prevent this submit and stay on your current page, or add an alert to the page you're going with this submit.

If you want to stay on your current page, try this:

```
jQuery(function($){

    function formSubmit(form) {
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data){
            $("#some-outer-container-with-form").html(data);
        });
        $("#form").submit(function(){ return formSubmit(form) }); //we need to rebind 
        return false;        
    }

    $("#form").submit(function(){ return formSubmit( $(this) ) });
});
```

Comment: I want stay on current page, but just reload the form-area. I did this with $().load();, but don't send the POST for the new form, and I need this.

Comment: I inserted e.preventDefault(); but nothing happens. The problem persists.

Comment: I'am discovered that the problem is more on top. The $("form") don't is recognize for the JQuery script file, it happens because the <form> is generated by the Ajax-Request for drawn the page on the center of template. Then the <form> never will be executed for JQuery. Above I edited my post and inserted the JQuery functions for load page on center of template.

Comment: you should not use .load(), instead get data parameter inside your callback, and do .html(data);

Comment: I edit the function carregaUrl2() above, but nothing happens.

Comment: I'am created a other post here, in the Stack Overflow for this problem, because after our discussions we discover that this problem is initially different from that presented here. Thanks.